# =FILTER arrayformula with

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[**Test sheet**](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1uYWzfgmeiP4JEKM5sMzbxfL2DCKLtfMiK5u_pnIbQY8/edit?usp=sharing)
I have an Options sheet that categorizes transactions based on their type. In the Transactions sheet, I add transactions with their corresponding category, and I am trying to create a formula where the corresponding category type is automatically added in the column next to it.

I have been able to create a partially working formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(FILTER(Options!C:C,Options!B:B=D31))
```

I want to expand it across all the cells in column E using an ARRAYFORMULA, but I can't seem to figure out how to have the Options!B:B=D with the corresponding cell. Making it =D31 I've been able to figure out, but having one formula at the bottom (at Ref 1) and then the right category type for each corresponding cell, I have not.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use in E2:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFNA(VLOOKUP(D2:D, Options!B:C, 2, 0)))
```

[image]